# Node.js TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

So the full text of the error is like this

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
```

What did I want to do ? I wanted to make a GET request dependent on a POST request.
How did I try to do this ?

```
const postPrinterData = (request, response) => {
  const printer_id = parseInt(request.body.printer_id, 10);
  
  console.log('Получен printer_id:', printer_id);

  getPrinter_material(printer_id, response);
};

const getPrinter_material = (printer_id, response) => {
  pool.connect((error, client, release) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }

    const query = {
      text: 'SELECT pr.printer_id, m.material FROM printer_material pm JOIN printer pr ON pm.printer_id = pr.printer_id JOIN material m ON pm.material_id = m.material_id WHERE pr.printer_id = $1;', 
      values: [printer_id],
    }

    client.query(query, (error, results) => {
      release();

      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }

      response.json([...results.rows]);
    });
  });
};
module.exports = {
  getPrinter_material,
  postPrinterData,
};
```

I export them here

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const db = require('./pool');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.use(cors());

app.get('/printer_material', db.getPrinter_material);

app.post('/printerData', db.postPrinterData);

http.createServer(app).listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`);
});
```

What was I trying to do to solve this error ?

```
console.log(results);
console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
```

I checked the output whether there is a result, whether it can be converted to JSON format, and the answer is yes. But I don't understand if there is a result, then why there is an error that I specified.
Me client code

```
const selectElement1 = document.getElementById('select1');
const selectElement2 = document.getElementById('select2');
const selectElement3 = document.getElementById('select3');
const departmentSelect = document.querySelector('#department');

function createOption(value, text) {
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = value;
  option.textContent = text;
  return option;
}

function loadSelectOptions1(url, selectElement) {
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(item => {
        const option = createOption(item.printer_id, item.printer);
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      // Обработать ошибку
    });
}

function loadSelectOptions2(url, selectElement) {
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(item => {
        const option = createOption(item.printer_id, item.material);
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      // Обработать ошибку
    });
}

function loadPrinters() {
  loadSelectOptions1('http://:3000/printerCB', selectElement2);
}

function loadMaterial() {
  loadSelectOptions2('http://:3000/printer_material_defolt', selectElement3);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  loadPrinters();
  loadMaterial();
});

Promise.all([
  fetch('http://:3000/departament').then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Ошибка загрузки данных');
    }
    return response.json();
  }),
  fetch('http://:3000/type_work').then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Ошибка загрузки данных');
    }
    return response.json();
  })
])
  .then(([departamentData, typeWorkData]) => {
    const departamentOptions = departamentData.map(item => createOption(item.departament, item.departament));
    departmentSelect.append(...departamentOptions);

    const typeOptions = typeWorkData.map(item => createOption(item.type_work, item.type_work));
    selectElement1.append(...typeOptions);

    selectElement1.addEventListener('change', () => {
      const selectedValue = selectElement1.value;

      selectElement2.innerHTML = '';

      if (selectedValue === 'Чёрно-белая печать') {
        loadSelectOptions1('http://:3000/printerCB', selectElement2);
      } else if (selectedValue === 'Цветная печать') {
        loadSelectOptions1('http://:3000/printerColor', selectElement2);
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });

selectElement2.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const selectedPrinter = selectElement2.value;

  // Отправить выбранный printer_id на сервер
  fetch('http://:3000/printerData', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ printer_id: selectedPrinter })
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Ошибка отправки данных');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: whats your client code?  show how you assign `results`

Comment: @Joe, I added my client code

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the error message indicates that the error was occured when you tried to pass Socket instance into `JSON.stringify()` and the `Socket` has a reference to itself. For example this code will cause a circular reference error.

```
const socket = {}; 
socket.anyKey = socket 
JSON.stringify(socket)
```

The most popular case is to **stringify objects `res`** and **`req`** received in callback of http server.

I think it's crutual to say that it works the same for the most popular framework **`express.js`**, since it is written on top of the built-in `node.js:http` library.
You can reproduce the same error with the same error message using just 1 line of code:

```
require('node:http').createServer({}, (req) => JSON.stringify(req)).listen(8080)
```

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
> --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
> |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
> --- property 'socket' closes the circle
> at JSON.stringify ()

I would recommend that you to not stringify objects with such a complex structure, but if you want to, there is a way to do it - a **replacer function for the `JSON.stringify`**. I think this solution will be sufficient in most cases.

```
const getCircularReplacer = () => {
    const seen = new WeakSet();
    return (key, value) => {
        if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
            if (seen.has(value)) {
                return;
            }
            seen.add(value);
        }
        return value;
    };
};
require('http').createServer({}, req => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(req, getCircularReplacer()))
}).listen(8080)
```